# Interacting with DOM for AJAX webpages?

Tags: javascript, webkit

hey guys, I'm not experienced with developing extensions, but I'm doing it to learn. I'd like to make an extension that blocks only certain twitter icons. By looking through this [tutorial](http://code.google.com/edu/submissions/html-css-javascript/) I have figured out a lot. I am able to the tweets from the DOM, check for the username, and disable the display of that image with JavaScript.

I got this far by creating a fake page, let's call it twitter.html, that looks a little like this:

```
<html>
    <div class="stream-item" data-item-type="tweet">
        <div class="tweet-image">
            <img src="abc.jpg" data-user-id="1234">
        </div>
    </div>
```

.....

```
<script src="utility.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tweets = getElementsByClass("tweet");
for (var i =  0; i < tweets.length; i++) {
    var tweet = tweets[i];
    var name = tweet.getAttribute("data-screen-name");
    if (name.toLowerCase() == 'some-username'.toLowerCase()) {
        var icon = tweet.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
        icon.style.display='none';
    }
}

</script>

</html>
```

So *hiding* the images isn't the problem, but getting the coe to run at the right time is.
I'm using Safari extension builder allows me to supply a main page, as well as before-load and after-load js files. However, the page load is "finished" before any tweets get loaded due to the AJAX stuff the real twitter.com uses.

How do I get my js code to run *after* tweets are loaded?

Comment: The code you provided assumes all the data is loaded. What loads the data? If you're using someone else's API, then they've probably provided a way for you to hook into a 'complete' event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Yes exactly it assumes all the data is loaded. All of that is pretty much to apply a style to certain elements. I'm not using any API, other than the 'Document Object Model' of the page. I'm just trying to do it via an extension. Very similar to the [Facebook Neue](http://soggysh.it/facebook-neue/) extension

Comment: To answer your question about what loads the data: When the browser goes to twitter.com, I guess it get's served a page with some javascript that loads quickly. Then that javascript probably does a bunch of asynchronous http requests to load the tweets. Don't take this as 100% accurate, because I'm not a web dev, and know very little about this subject.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should listen to the DOMNodeInserted, which is called... well, every time a DOM Node is Inserted :)
Once received, check if the node is of a type that interests you, and proceed from there.

I've took the liberty of modifying your code to accommodate the changes. I've successfully tested this in Chrome.

```
window.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted",
    function(event){ 
        var streamItem = event.target;
        if (streamItem == null)
            return;

        if (streamItem.getAttribute('class') != 'stream-item')
            return;

        var tweet = streamItem.getElementsByClassName("tweet",streamItem)[0];
        var name = tweet.getAttribute("data-screen-name");
        if (name.toLowerCase() == 'some-username'.toLowerCase()) 
        {
            var icon = tweet.getElementsByTagName("img")[0];
            icon.style.display='none';
        }
    }, 
    false);
```